# UE4 Complex Collision, Phys Material Override not working

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Below you can see the Phys Mat set in the StaticMeshActor, which has been placed into the world.
[image: Phys Mat Override]

When I am tracing with a complex trace it says, that my Phys Mat is the default one.
When I am tracing with a simple trace, it says that the phys mat is the one that I set in the editor.

I read online, that this should also work with complex traces.
[image: Complex Collision in the Unreal Doc]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to make this within the editor. But I coded my way around it. Basically, I made a simple trace from the complex Hit about 10 units further to 'secure' my new trace. Then I just swapped out my Phys Material from my complex trace with the Phys Material from my simple trace.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues with this too. When the override or static mesh physical materials wouldn't work, usually setting the physical material in the material instance or parent material will do the trick. In some cases, I duplicate material instances so I have one for each physical material needed, and then apply the new material instances to the appropriate static meshes.